# Java file executable, but command line says it's not a valid win32 application

Tags: java, python, command-prompt

I'm practicing for Google Code Jam, and some of their problems require an interactive solution. I wrote a solution in java and ran

`javac filename.java` in the command prompt. When I run `java filename`, the file runs perfectly. However, when I call this file in combination with python scripts, I get the error message `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

The commented out text below shows what the Google provided python scripts require me to run in command line. So I typed out `python interactive_runner.py python testing_tool.py 0 -- ./filename`, and that's when I got the win32 error. Is there something that I'm forgetting to do?

```
# For example:
# python interactive_runner.py python testing_tool.py 0 -- ./my_binary
#
# This will run the first test set of a python judge called "testing_tool.py"
# that receives the test set number (starting from 0) via command line parameter
# with a solution compiled into a binary called "my_binary".
```

Comment: "with a solution compiled into a binary" - are you sure java is allowed? It doesn't compile into a binary.

Comment: @jordanm They do allow Java, and I can verify this because on their solution page (https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000000130/0000000000000523), they have a Java solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly run a Java program - it is not a Win32 application. You have to either

a) Compile the Java program into a jar file, and run it using `java -jar filename.jar`
or

b) Run it using `java filename.java'

You need to find a way of supplying one of those two commands to the Python script. I think this should work: 
`python interactive_runner.py python testing_tool.py 0 -- java filename.java`

Comment: Thank you! Running ```python interactive_runner.py python testing_tool.py 0 -- java filename``` worked for me (excluded .java)

Comment: Sounds as if your Java source file does not have a file extension. That would be unusual for Linux/Unix but is very bad practice on Windows.